# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 pjmedia pjsip

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sip, pjsip

I just add library and framework of PJSIP to my XCODE project such as Simulator, Device and Third Party but when I build my project it show error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_pjmedia_get_video_format_info", referenced from:
      _ios_factory_create_stream in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(ios_dev.o)
  "_pjmedia_format_get_video_format_detail", referenced from:
      _ios_factory_create_stream in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(ios_dev.o)
  "_pjmedia_format_init_video", referenced from:
      _ios_factory_init in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(ios_dev.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I try to Google the solution but it seem not help. Please share your idea, I think i miss some configuration or library. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look in to this question asked on SO earlier

[Trouble of compilation on xcode4.2 for pjsip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968725/trouble-of-compilation-on-xcode4-2-for-pjsip)